# PostgreSQL : getting the Results of a Function

Tags: java, xml, postgresql

I have an PostgreSQL Function which returns me an XML where the whole infos of my table are.

This is my function:

```
/* get all cat names */
create function cat_names() returns xml as $$
select to_xml('select name FROM cat_Infos;');
$$ language sql;
```

to get the results I do the following:

```
ResultSet rs = sql.executeQuery("select cat_names()");
while (rs.next()) {
   // This is where I actually thought  that I could pass the XML I get, to my DOMParser. 
   //  I thought about something like this:
   DOMParser dom = new DOMParser();
   dom.setImputString(//Xml I get from the resultset)
}
```

The problem is, I actually have no idea how to get the Xml from the ResultSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
 String xml = rs.getString(1)
```

to get the XML String